# Scrape multiple websites with beautifulsoup without being blocked

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect the daily total market capitalization of cryptocurrencies for over 2000 days from coinmarketcap.com (from 2012-01-01 to today). The total market capitalization for each day is on a different webpage, so I scape all those pages with beautifulsoup in python. However, my requests seem to get blocked because I query too fast and frequently. Is there a way to scrape those pages without being blocked? My code for web-scraping is below:

```py
print("Collecting Total Market Capitalizations...")
all_dates = [x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))]
output_name = "data/marketcap.csv"
content = [["Date", "TotalMarketCap"]]
for d in all_dates:
    print("We are at " + d, end="\r")
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/" + d.replace("-", "")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    row = soup.find_all('strong')
    if len(row) > 0:
        row = row[0]         
        curr_cap = row.getText().split("$")[1].replace(",", "")
        content.append([str(d), str(curr_cap)])
print("")
with open(output_name, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(content)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of the following two things:

1. Use different IP Address on every request so the website doesn't realise that it's the same client trying to access the same resource.
2. Make your code (if you have enough time) sleep/pause between two consecutive page fetches.